# 'Complete' requestAnimationFrame animation when tab is in background

Tags: javascript, animation

**TLDR** : Is there an easy way to skip the animation if it could have occurred in the background?

So rAF is meant to stop executing when the tab is hidden. That is absolutely fine and what I want. The problem is that the animation just continues from where it paused when the tab regains focus. This works fine for most situations but there are some cases where this isn't desirable.

I'm creating a web application and have a splash screen which animates once the content has loaded. If the user swaps to another tab it would be better for the user if the animation had completed when they switch back to the app rather than having to wait for it to complete as the animation only really hides the content loading.

Is there a way to get the time since last called parameter that is passed to the animation step function to take into account the time the tab was in the background? Or is there another simple way to detect if the animation should have completed by now and skip to the end state rather than animate?